# Spring batch JdbcpagingItem reader throwing exception when no data returned by query: The value is not set for the parameter number 1

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-batch

I am running a spring batch step with jdbcpagingitemreader reading the data from SQL server in multiple threads using task executor. Batch runs fine when there is data returned by the query. But in case there is no data created after the last batch execution then its throwing below exception.

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT TOP 10 name,age,dept_name,EMP_SK FROM BTR_OWNER.EMPLOYEE WHERE and created_dttm >=(Select Max(CREATED_DTTM) from BTR_OWNER.SUMMARY where BATCH_NM='SPRING_BATCH' and COMPLETION_STAT='COMPLETED')) AND ((EMP_SK > ?)) ORDER BY EMP_SK ASC]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The value is not set for the parameter number 1.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 1.

This is how I configured the paging item reader and step:

```
return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<BtsEmployeeDTO>().name("BtsEmployeeReader")
                .dataSource(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource())
                .selectClause(SqlConstants.BTS_EMP_RET_SELECT )
                .fromClause(SqlConstants.BTS_EMP_RET_FROM)
                .whereClause(SqlConstants.BTS_EMP_RET_WHERE)
                .sortKeys(Collections.singletonMap("EMP_SK", Order.ASCENDING))
                .fetchSize(10)
                .pageSize(10)
                .rowMapper(new EmployeeRowMapper()).build();
 @Bean
 public Step BtsEmployeeRet() { 
     return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("BtsEmployeeRet")
             .<BtsEmployeeDTO, BtsEmployeeDTO>chunk(10)
                .reader(jdbcPagingItemReader())
                .writer(getEmpPagingWriter())
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

You're affected by this bug in Spring Batch: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3898.

It has been fixed since versions 4.3.4 and 4.2.8. If you can, you should upgrade to the latest patch release of 4.3.x or 4.2.x.

If you really can't upgrade, it should be possible to extend `JdbcPagingItemReader` and override the method `doReadPage` to contain the fix that solved the issue in Spring Batch itself.